# How to resolve the 504 error on AWS Cloudfront EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront

I have the following setup for my website on windows server:

1. Domain registered in Route 53
2. EC2 Instance running on windows server
3. Cloud front to serve the EC2 origin using the distribution with the option to get user redirected from HTTP to HTTPs.
4. Public certificate deployed on cloud front.

Here is what is working:

1. The EC2 Origin, every page works on http protocol.
2. Domain access, correctly redirects user from http to https
3. The first website page loads without issues.

ISSUE:
The issue is the error 504 which is displayed when any of the link is clicked on the website. Here is the complete error detail:

> 504 ERROR
>
> The request could not be satisfied.
>
> CloudFront attempted to establish a connection with the origin, but either the attempt failed or the origin closed the connection. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
> If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
> Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)

I have included all the route options to accept http and https.

Comment: have you resolved this?